Ubuntu Installation error during dual boot
I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 11 for dual boot.
I shrank the C:\ drive and created two new partitions as E:\ and F:\ with unallocated space. Not sure if it's relevant, but I have a yellow symbol sign on C:\ after doing this.
I inserted a USB flash drive and was able to boot into Ubuntu, but the "disk selection" step reports failure as I press the '+' sign.
I have disabled Secure Boot and Fast Boot options. Screenshots of the error messages are attached below.
'ubiquity crashed with typerror in partman_dialog(): 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'






You may find this LinuxConfig article of help
